# Dispose a context and create again

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm adding a lot of data inside the database. I want, after 9999 files managed, dispose the context and create another one and keep adding. I'm using this code, but it's not working. Do you have any suggestions? I'm using C# and EFCore.

```
VMContext _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VMContext>();

foreach (string filename in filesnumber)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        aInt++;

        //DO SOMETHING
        _repository.ImportAdd(_context, newDATA);

        if (aInt == 9999)
        {
            _repository.Save(_context);
            _repository.Dispose(_context);
            _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VMContext>();
        }
    }
}

_repository.Save(_context);
_repository.Dispose(_context);
```

Edit: The error I get is this, after aInt is 9999 it save the context and dispose it, when I go to the next _repository.ImportAdd, I get :

[image]

Comment: *"but it's not working"* - what is not working? Please be more specific.

Comment: I don't see the limit in the code of 9999  files, by the way, I don't understand what you are doing, files or database? what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: This seems a [classic XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Probably you have a different problem somewhere but you haven't explained the real problem and just showed us what you think is the solution to your original problem but then you have another problem.

Comment: as it says, it may be caused if you are calling Dispose() on the context, what is exactly what you are doing, have you tried to remove that line?

Comment: You need to setup your DI so that you'll always get a new instance. My guess is that you configured it so that you always get the same instance while in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

you have `_repository.Dispose(_context);` in your code

```
                        if (aInt == 9999)
                        {
                            _repository.Save(_context);
                            _repository.Dispose(_context);
                            _context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VMContext>();
                        }
```

however when repository instance is created after first 9999 items?

probably the `_repository.Dispose(_context);` should not be called

it is enough just clear the repository (to remove all items added with `_repository.ImportAdd` that were saved) and do not dispose context and do not create a new one

like below:

```
if (aInt == 9999)
{
  _repository.Save(_context);
  //_repository.ClearItems(_context); 
  _context.DataVul.Clear(); // just to check will it work or not before new _repository.ClearItems method creation
}
```

UPD error you have shown says that you should not dispose context since it is diposed by the DI container. DI container disposes all `IDisposable` usually by itself.

Comment: It's what I need! I just need to clear the context, but how i clear it from previous 9999 items (already added in db)?

Comment: @RobNone there is `_repository.ImportAdd(_context, newDATA);` that adds item to context. Create a new repository method `ClearItems` that will clear items added to the context.

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering how clear items in the method _repository.ClearItems(_context)? Which code i have to use?

Comment: @RobNone do you have access to the `_repository.ImportAdd` method source code? Check this method (how it adds items to the context). Probably some context property is used to store the items list, like `Items`. So you can call `Items.Clear()` in the new method or to initialise a new instance for this property.

Comment: I have this on the repository public void ImportAdd(VMContext _context,  DataVul newDATA) { _context.DataVul.Add(newDATA); }

Comment: @RobNone so you can clear the context using `_context.DataVul.Clear()` inside of the `if (aInt == 9999)`. I will update the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205744/discussion-between-rob-none-and-oleksa).